# Closure notation help

Tags: relations

Example:
Let <· be the relation on integers defined by x <· y if x + 1 = y.

• The transitive closure of <· is <.

• The reflexive and transitive closure of <· is ≤.

What do the dots mean next to the greater than and less than symbols?

Comment: It's just defined in the very first sentence. "$< \cdot$" is just any symbol, like $R$ could be.

Answer (score 1):

Those dots are just what the writer of the problem chose to decorate the $<$ symbol with when defining his relation. They have no general meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the help, wow I feel stupid haha

Comment: @user3768911 You're welcome. No need ever to feel stupid. Many math questions look easy once you know the answer ...